# Overwriting bytes of an exe in hex

Tags: c, io, binaryfiles

I want to change the logic of an exe by changing the binary. One of the hex values in the exe is 75 which I have to change to 74 (JNE to JE in x86 assembly). I know it's the 1276th byte of the file, but how do I do this?

Here's what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fileH = fopen ("foo", "r+");
    fseek(fileH, 1276, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite("74", 1, 1, fileH);
    fclose(fileH);
    return 0;
}
```

Also for some reason I'm getting 'fileH' undeclared, even though I included stdio and have FILE in all uppercase. I wasn't able to find anyone else with this problem. Running this on ubuntu

Comment: `"74"` is a string literal, not a byte with the value 74. If you want to write a byte, create a variable of type `unsigned char`, initialise it and pass its address to `fwrite`.

Comment: There's also the issue of whether the exe contains checksums or CRCs or other protection against tampering.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I'm getting `fileH` undeclared"*? This compiles cleanly in MSVC (although comment from @MOehm applies).

Comment: @Weather Vane I'm not sure whether it's my compiler or os (gcc 4.4.3, ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: Could you post the error message here verbatim, please?

Comment: It's points to line with fopen: 'fileH' undeclared (first use in this function. Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a byte value to write to the file. And the 8086 opcode for `JE` is `74` in hexadecimal, not decimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char byt = 0x74;
    FILE *fileH = fopen ("foo.txt", "r+");
    if (fileH == NULL)
        return 1;
    if (fseek(fileH, 3, SEEK_SET))
        return 1;
    if (fwrite(&byt, 1, 1, fileH) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (fclose(fileH))
        return 1;
    printf("File updated\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As a demo using a small text file, content before:

```
0123456789
```

and after:

```
012t456789
```

I have no idea why your compiler refuses `fileH` except that sometimes a text editor can leave a rogue unseen character where there should not be one. The solution there, is to delete and retype the offending line.

Comment: History: as it happens I earned my first £100 for a day's work (and site visit) by altering some third-party code, changing a single byte to convert the logical name `/profile` to the device name `.profile`, to access Apple's massive 10 MB external hard drive!

Answer (score 0):

```
   int main()
    {
        FILE *fileH = fopen ("foo", "r+");
        fseek(fileH, 1276, SEEK_SET);
        putc(0x74,fileH);
    }
```

and xxd -p foo to dump in hex your file

Comment: Please, do not use `void main()` write `int main()` instead.

Comment: If you wan't rodrigo.